# Fastest way to Add and Subtract multiple parts of a List

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming, lists

I am doing some research where I have a List containing numbers. For example

```
{5,10,98,22,13,15}
```

What is a fast algorithm to calculate all possible sums and differences from these? Eventually I will want to do the same thing for a list of 400+ numbers.

Some examples in the final set

```
index0+index1=5+10=15
index0+index3+index4=5+22+13=40
index0+index2-index5=5+98-15=88
index3-index4=22-13=9
```

What I am thinking now is 3 *for* loops. One to move through the array, one to keep track of how many numbers to skip, and one for the number of skips. But that seems slow.

Ahh I guess my answer is unsolvable bc of P=NP. I see from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: (What are the conditions that would allow you to _not_ compute each and every subset's sum? given the empty set has sum 0, how do you get the sum of every subset of cardinality 1?)

Comment: There are about $3^n$ different sums or differences that can be written out of $n$ numbers, assuming no repeats. In you example $3^6=729$ and $3^{400}$ is a lot.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė oh thanks for that. I guess this task is impossible. What about just addition or just subtraction. Still as big?

Comment: @SethKitchen, just addition would be about $2^n$ which is still a lot. The problem is not that there are too many operations, but too many terms. For example, if you just wanted sums of pairs of numbers (so, not 5+22+13), you'd only get about $n^2$ which is a lot less.

Comment: Short answer, what you are trying to do is probably misguided. You need to rethink the algorithm to something with a lot less calculations or subsets